# Why does MPMoviePlayerController prevent resumption of audio after the movie ends?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudioplayer

I have a class that plays a repeating background music loop with an `AVAudioPlayer`, and on specific occasion, plays a full-screen video with its own sound track using `MPMoviePlayerController`. In order to to have only one track at a time, I stop the background music before launching the video:

```
-(void)startVideo{
    [backgroundMusic stop];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"videofile" ofType:@"m4v"]]];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoOver) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
    [mp.moviePlayer play];
    [mp release];
}

-(void)videoOver{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
    if(![backgroundMusic play]){
         NSLog(@"bad: can't resume bg music!");
         [backgroundMusic release];
         backgroundMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"videofile" ofType:@"m4v"]] error:NULL];
         backgroundMusic.delegate = self; 
         backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops = -1; 
         [backgroundMusic play];
    }
}
```

The resumption worked fine without recreating the `AVAudioPlayer` object (i.e. the `play` method returned YES) on analogous code on os versions up to and including 3.2. But on iOS4, the `play` method always returns NO, and has to recreate the object. Why is that, and can I get to resume the background track properly (I have cases where the solution used above is unacceptable.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out. It turns out that in iOS 3.2 and above, when a video finishes playing, it goes into `MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused` state rather than `MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped`, and in order to make it release the hardware, you have to explicitly call the `stop` method on MPMoviePlayerController after it finishes playing before trying to resume `AVAudioPlayer`.